# Не работает aspect

Tags: java, aop

У меня есть метод, который я бы хотел логировать.

```
@ApiLogBefore
public ResponseEntity save(@RequestParam("transactionId") String transactionId) throws JsonProcessingException {
...
}
```

Есть аннотация, через которую я хочу исполнять аспект:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ApiLogBefore {
}
```

Пока она пустая.
Есть аспект:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ApiLogAspectProcessor {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(ApiLogBefore)")
    public void logProcessor() {
    }

    @Before(value = "logProcessor()")
    public void before() {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        log.debug(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    }
}
```

При запуске теста на метод save в консоль, как я понимаю, должен вывестись output. Но даже не заходит в метод, брейкпоинт не ловит тоже ничего.

Зависимости:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version: '5.1.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.9.2'
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.9.2'
```

Подскажите, где может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказалось, чтобы всё заработало, необходимо было пометить конфиг аннотацией `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`